# Install web service server on Blade system

Tags: linux, jboss, blade, web-services

I need to install a webservice server coding in java & running in JBoss AS onto a blade server with Linux OS. Anybody knows what way to make use all the power of that blade? Or just install it as install on other system?

In my point of view, there are two ways I could do:

1. Implement a webservice "server" which accept the incoming request, and then deliver to its "client" webservice. So we would run one instance of server and many instance of client.
2. Other way is just improve the current implementation, accept incoming request and try to use multi-thread as many as possible to maximum the performance of the blade server.

How do you think?

This is very strange to me so I would very thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Since a blade server is simply a server in a special chassis, one would treat it the same as any other system.

Comment: I would like to know a way that maximize the performance of my server in the blade server. Any idea?